# Trying to install metasploit

Tags: installation, metasploit

I am trying to install `metasploit`. I tried using bundle install, which produced the below output.
I don't understand why I can't install `metasploit`, I have tried a lot of different methods. I am using Windows 7 X64 on a ThinkCentre Edge92z Touchscreen Computer. I have the devkit installed and Ruby 2.0.0 x64 edition.

```
c:\Users\Flip\Downloads\metasploit-framework-master>gem install network_interfac
e -v '0.0.1' --platform=ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing network_interface:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extcon
f.rb

[*] Running che`enter code here`cks for netifaces code...
[*] Warning : this platform as not been tested
checking for getifaddrs()... no
checking for getnameinfo()... yes
checking for SIOCGIFCONF in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netine
t/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGSIZIFCONF in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,net
inet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFHWADDR in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,neti
net/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFADDR in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netine
t/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFFLAGS in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netin
et/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFDSTADDR in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,net
inet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFBRDADDR in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,net
inet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGIFNETMASK in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,net
inet/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGLIFNUM in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netine
t/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGLIFCONF in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,netin
et/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for SIOCGLIFFLAGS in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/ioctl.h,net/if.h,neti
net/in.h,arpa/inet.h... no
checking for net/if_dl.h... no
checking for netash/ash.h... no
checking for netatalk/at.h... no
checking for netax25/ax25.h... no
checking for neteconet/ec.h... no
checking for netipx/ipx.h... no
checking for netpacket/packet.h... no
checking for netrose/rose.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr.sa_len in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,net/if.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_at in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,ne
tinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ax25 in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,
netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_dl in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,ne
tinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_eon in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,n
etinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_in in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,ne
tinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_in6 in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,n
etinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_inarp in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h
,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ipx in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,n
etinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_iso in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,n
etinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ns in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,ne
tinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_un in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,ne
tinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_x25 in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,n
etinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_rose in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,
netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ash in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,n
etinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ec in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,ne
tinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_ll in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,ne
tinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_atmpvc in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.
h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_atmsvc in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.
h,netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_dn in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,ne
tinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_irda in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,
netinet/in.h... no
checking for struct sockaddr_llc in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,sys/un.h,net/if.h,n
etinet/in.h... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating network_interface_ext-x64-mingw32.def
compiling netifaces.c
netifaces.c: In function 'rbnetifaces_s_interface_info':
netifaces.c:794:11: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'strlen' d
iffer in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
In file included from c:\rubydevkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.
2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winnt.h:1446:0,
                 from c:\rubydevkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.
2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:137,
                 from c:\rubydevkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.
2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:59,
                 from c:\rubydevkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.
2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winsock2.h:23,
                 from c:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/i
nclude/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/win32.h:40,
                 from c:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/i
nclude/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/defines.h:153,
                 from c:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/i
nclude/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:70,
                 from c:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/i
nclude/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from netifaces.c:1:
c:\rubydevkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w
64-mingw32/include/intrin.h:434:5: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is
 of type 'LPBYTE'
netifaces.c:794:11: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'rb_str_ne
w' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
In file included from c:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/i
nclude/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1568:0,
                 from c:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/i
nclude/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from netifaces.c:1:
c:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby
/intern.h:672:7: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'LPBYTE'
netifaces.c:794:11: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'rb_str_ne
w_cstr' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
In file included from c:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/i
nclude/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1568:0,
                 from c:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/i
nclude/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from netifaces.c:1:
c:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby
/intern.h:673:7: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'LPBYTE'
linking shared-object network_interface_ext.so
netifaces.o: In function `rbnetifaces_s_interface_info':
C:\Users\Flip\Downloads\metasploit-framework-master\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gem
s\network_interface-0.0.1\ext\network_interface_ext/netifaces.c:717: undefined r
eference to `GetAdaptersInfo'
netifaces.o: In function `rbnetifaces_s_interfaces':
C:\Users\Flip\Downloads\metasploit-framework-master\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gem
s\network_interface-0.0.1\ext\network_interface_ext/netifaces.c:559: undefined r
eference to `GetAdaptersInfo'
netifaces.o: In function `rbnetifaces_s_addresses':
C:\Users\Flip\Downloads\metasploit-framework-master\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gem
s\network_interface-0.0.1\ext\network_interface_ext/netifaces.c:238: undefined r
eference to `GetAdaptersInfo'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [network_interface_ext.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-
master/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/network_interface-0.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/lib/r
uby/gems/2.0.0/gems/network_interface-0.0.1/ext/network_interface_ext/gem_make.o
ut

c:\Users\Flip\Downloads\metasploit-framework-master>gem install pcaprub
Fetching: pcaprub-0.11.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pcaprub:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extcon
f.rb

[*] Running checks for pcaprub code...
platform is x64-mingw32
checking for pcap_open_live() in -lpcap... no
checking for pcap_setnonblock() in -lpcap... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating pcaprub-x64-mingw32.def
compiling pcaprub.c
pcaprub.c:8:18: fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [pcaprub.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-
master/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pcaprub-0.11.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/Flip/Downloads/metasploit-framework-master/ruby/lib/r
uby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pcaprub-0.11.3/ext/pcaprub/gem_make.out

c:\Users\Flip\Downloads\metasploit-framework-master>
```

Answer (score 2):

See if you have these installed:
-----------------
libcap-devel - Libraries and header files for the libpcap library.
libpcap - A system-independent interface for user-level packet capture.
-----------------
...your error is telling you that it can't compile the pcap source file(pcap.c) into an object file(pcap.o) because it is missing the pcap header file(pcap.h).

```
compiling pcaprub.c
pcaprub.c:8:18: fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
```

...you could also use this command as root to see if it exists

```
#find / -iname pcap.h
```

...or if you are using windows you might need to install WinPcap.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install WinPcap, as well as download WinPcap Developer's Pack (found [here](https://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm)). The latter contains the needed pcap.h.

You have to extract the WinPcap Developer's pack in `c:\WpdPack\`

Click [here](https://github.com/pcaprub/pcaprub/wiki/Windows-Installation) for a more detailed guide.

Answer (score -1):

i dont think you need to use command prompt, the download will be on the meatsploit website i think

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).